# Derived types as part of XML messages

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, schema

We have created a couple of XML-Schemas where a field refers to an abstract type, but at runtime the messsage will contain a type derived from that abstract type. The Java code handles that properly by default, but I am puzzled, if and how the XML-unmarshalling will handle that. Will the Java<=>XML code created by JAXB be able to handle that out of the box or do we have to do some handholding?

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat abstract question so here's a somewhat abstract answer.

JAXB will most probably be able to handle that:

- Specific type can be specified via `xsi:type`.  Please see [this post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html) by Blais Doughan. This method allows using a specific type in the runtime. You'll get the same element but the `xsi:type` will specify the specific type used. For instance you could get `<geometry xsi:type="polygonType" .../>`
- Sometimes inheritance is modeled using substitution groups, see the `@XmlElementDecl` [`substitutionHeadName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementDecl.html#substitutionHeadName())/[`substitutionHeadNamespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementDecl.html#substitutionHeadNamespace()). In this case you could replace an abstract element with a specific element. For instance an abstract `_Geometry` element with a specific `Polygon` element.

JAXB supports both methods but through different constructs.